# it is possible to put different layouts for child items in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, expandablelistview

I'm a new developer with android and I'm trying to put different layouts for child items in Expandable List View but I can't found the complete tutorial to do this so if is possible to do this, please help with a link for a good tutorial or a simple code source for this type of Expandable List View.
thanks

Comment: you need set different layouts for each group or each child?

Comment: for each child and my class is extendable from ListFragment

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techiecommunity.net/Android/Android-ExpandableListView-Layout-Example 
this tutorial can solve the problem mentioned in my question but i still have a problem because my class extendable a ListFragment and for this example extends  ExpandableListActivity, so there is a solution for that ??

Answer (score 0):

Just don't extend `ExpandableListActivity`. I also extends a `Fragment` and it works fine.

Then use the correct method :

```
((ExpandableListView) getView().findViewById( R.id.list).setAdapter( m_expandableListAdapter);
```