# Expandable Listview Issues in android

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I am use listview within the expandable listview as a child. When i click on the parent item then child is expanded with listview. but the listview show only the single value where i set adapter with multiple value.

Can any one help how to solved this issues?

Comment: Why do you need the nested listview as a child of the expandable listview?
All elements of the nested listview should be added as children of the expandable listview.

Comment: Because i want to create header listview(Like contact list in our device) within the expandable Listview.

Comment: Use ExpandableListView with two types of children.
Each child can use different layout and behaviour, so one child can be your header and all other child are the contacts

Comment: can you please give me the reference link?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following question:

[Different layouts for child items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008498/it-is-possible-to-put-different-layouts-for-child-items-in-expandablelistview)

Try search in Stack overflow, there are many questions and also many tutorials over the web.